# Adding multiple elements in a table column

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add multiple table cells elements under each of my heading cells but it isn't working.

Here is a screen for better understanding :

[image]

I would like to have for each of my category, say for example,

Category 1 : to have below "Brandon" others names like => Steph, Emily, John, etc.

So far I made with a line break but it doesn't work as expected: each item should be in a separated row.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Category 1</th>
    <th>Category 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Emil<br>Brandon</td>
    <td>Tobias</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes exactly each item should be in a separated row, sorry for making it not clear at all. I updated my post. @isherwood

Comment: Oh lala, that was a stupid question, sorry I'm overwhelmed haha.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add another row.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Category 1</th>
    <th>Category 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Emil</td>
    <td>Tobias</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Brandon</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```